# Non void Method invoking without assigning return value in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm

What does the JVM when a non-void method is invoked without a recipient object for the returned value? 
It just destroy the returned object in the moment that doesn't find a recipient? or it leaves the returned object to be managed with the trash collector? Or something else?. For example:

```
public class PrincipalClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        returnStringMethod();
    }
    public static String returnStringMethod() {
        return "Hello, Java world!";
    }
}
```

What happens to the "Hello, Java world!" that was returned? In what time is destroyed?

Comment: This question might already have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977883/where-does-return-value-go-in-java-if-no-variable-assigned-to-accept-it

Comment: No Java method returns an object, though many of them return *references* to objects.  If such a reference is ignored then it is lost.  As an entirely independent matter, an object to which there are no live references in the VM is eligible for garbage collection.  Given that there can be multiple references to the same object, there is no particular connection at this level of generality between a method's return value being ignored and the disposition of any object it may have referred to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you ordered a meal. The meal came in disposable boxes. You took out out the food, ate it. Now the boxes are useless to you.What do you do with them..? Discard them. Same goes with Java GC. When any object is not referenced through any object, or is unapproachable, it gets next time gc is fired. One good way to see this is open jvisualvm and keep tracking String literal and then fire the gc. You would see things in real-time.

I hope this helps..!

Comment: oh, ok, i didn't knew open jvisualvm, thanks for the extra recommendation @RajanSingh

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the returned value/reference is simply discarded. Think of it as a local variable that immediately goes out of scope.

Furthermore, since there are no live references to this it gets eligible for GC. Hence, at that some point in the future (not right away) the object will be GCed.

Comment: To make things more confusing, this is probably put into the String pool so it won't be garbage collected.

Comment: Yes this is somewhat a special case. But in general this is how objects get handled.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile your program, e.g. using `javac` and run the command `javap -c PrincipalClass` (`javap` is a command shipped with the JDK), you will see the following output:

```
Compiled from "PrincipalClass.java"
public class PrincipalClass {
  public PrincipalClass();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #2                // Method returnStringMethod:()Ljava/lang/String;
       3: pop
       4: return

  public static java.lang.String returnStringMethod();
    Code:
       0: ldc           #3                // String Hello, Java world!
       2: areturn
}
```

The crucial part is the method `main` consisting of the bytecode instructions `invokestatic`, `pop`, `return`.

The `invokestatic` instruction will invoke the method `returnStringMethod` and leave a reference to the `String` on the operand stack. The subsequent `pop` instruction will remove the topmost stack entry, i.e. the reference. After that instruction, there is no reference to the string from the current method. So it was eligible for garbage collection if it wasn’t a string literal which stays referenced from the code. Specifically, it gets associated with the `ldc` instruction within the `returnStringMethod()`.

In principle, the `pop` instruction is not necessary here, as the `return` instruction will destroy the entire stack frame of the current method, including its operand stack.

In either case, the answer is that it is subject to the garbage collector, which may find out at a later time that there are no references to the object. That’s at least how it works formally. There’s also an optimizer within the JVM which may detect if a method ignores an object created directly within a called method and optimize this particular code. However, the result is more like never creating the object in the first place, rather than destroying it immediately after. And this optimizer only looks at code which turned out to be performance relevant.

The other point is, that for your simple program, the garbage collector will likely never run, as it is not needed in this short execution time. The entire heap memory will be released at once when the JVM terminates.

Comment: this could be a potentially easy optimization for an AOT compiler too